# How to link that "logged in" in "you must be logged in to post a comment" with custom login page on WordPress?

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

How to link that "logged in" in "you must be logged in to post a comment" for a post on WordPress to custom login page. So that when the user clicks on that "logged in" gets redirected to the custom login page not to the wp-login.php. Please help.

Comment: Do you want to enable that user must be logged in in order to post a comment?

Comment: yes that is already enabled.

Comment: Okay so you only want users to be redirected to a front-end user login page.

Comment: Yeah to my customed login page  with custom permalink.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/ plugin to create a front-end user login/signup page. Or if you want to customize your `wp-login.php` using this http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/ plugin will be better.

Comment: I already have all this. All I need is to redirect users to my custom login page when they click on that "logged in".

Comment: It should automatically redirect to the login page though. Please give some minutes to check this for you.

Comment: Thanks for help but when I deactivate the plugin rename wp login. Then it automatically redirects.

Comment: Do you have both plugin installed or only one?

Comment: Here, you can use this string `<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Login">Login</a>` to redirect to login page and after logged in returned to the current page. To customize your login page you can use this http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login plugin.